# Published google sheet webpage url opens the published page itself

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_0RgbYoR1x6zTYXZEJ-eHpcVulRmRNbF2Y6TnGN4ZWU/edit#gid=0). I put a link in A1 cell to open the same sheet after publish. The workbook-sheet is public with edit permission. After published, the link becomes '#gid=0'. I am redirected to [the published page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR65f8v3r55qpxBBcJDjTeLKSX8UTmyj_9HTT7Pd4Wf6NEh0ll0Pcvn84oIQmMM62t8BbO2EwsLPp8Q/pubhtml), instead of the editable google sheet. What is the issue? How can I make it work? spent hours without luck.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it here on my end. It opens the sheet in editable format. Could you perhaps change the url to 

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1\_0RgbYoR1x6zTYXZEJ-eHpcVulRmRNbF2Y6TnGN4ZWU/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_0RgbYoR1x6zTYXZEJ-eHpcVulRmRNbF2Y6TnGN4ZWU/edit?usp=sharing) instead?

Comment: @CenturyTuna The solution you have provided works! Please post it as the answer. I accept it.

Comment: posted it as an answer, glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

The published URL format and sharing URL format is different. Use this URL instead:

```
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_0RgbYoR1x6zTYXZEJ-eHpcVulRmRNbF2Y6TnGN4ZWU/edit?usp=sharing
```

Reference:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965